# Как объяснить слитное или раздельное написание наречий?

Tags: наречия

Как объяснить? И правильно ли написаны они?

Запомнить навек, навеки, навеки вечные, навсегда, сохранить доныне, разбить вдребезги, темным-темно, спрашивать по русскому языку, без ведома, без запроса.

Comment: Запомнить навек, навеки, навеки вечные, навсегда, сохранить доныне - это наречия с пространственным и временным значением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запомнить КАК? на какое время7в какой степени?- навек, навеки,  навсегда - наречие,слитно; сохранить  КАК ДОЛГО? - доныне-наречие, разбить КАК?- вдребезги-наречие(без приставки не употребляется), темным-темно(повторение однокоренных слов);

без  чего?-без ведома, без чего?-без запроса.-наречные выражения =сущ.+ предлог;

на что?-на веки какие?вечные,спрашивать по чему?- языку, какому?-русскому - сущ.+прилагательное - раздельно